# Zoom on UIScrollView after applying any "transform" in subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I've a UIScrollView with other subviews inside an UIImageWiew and I need to rotate the whole content, so I take this road:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([self.orientation floatValue]);
```

Good, works perfectly.

Being the ImageView inside a scroll view, I also need to set zoomScale in order to resize image inside, and I do it in this way:

```
- (void)updateZoom {
    const float minZoom = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.imageView.image.size.width,
                        self.view.bounds.size.height / self.imageView.image.size.height);
    if (minZoom > 1) {
        return;
    }
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoom;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minZoom;
}
```

**updateZoom** has the effect to "reset" initial transformation, so image come back to original orientation.
Generally, each time I modify "zoomScale" property, orientation is restored.

**How can I keep both orientation both zoomScale?**

I suppose I need to do something in scrollView delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put a repo on GitHub that might help you. It is in Swift but it should do

[PhotoSlideShow-Swift](https://github.com/villyg/PhotoSlideShow-Swift)